# Accessing different WAN-side subnet

Tags: networking, routing, subnet, pfsense

What is the easiest way (that doesn't involve changing the IP of my terminal or my router) to access a subnet that neither of these devices are operating on?

The router broadcasts 192.168.1.0-255, in which my terminal sits. And I have a device with a static IP somewhere in the 10.0.0.0-255 range that sits on the local side of the external gateway but on the WAN-side of the router - I have surmised that it is a bridge of some kind, as the network refuses to cooperate without it.

My knowledge of static routes is limited - but I've attempted to add one for 10.0.0.0/24 to my external gateway in accordance with similar problems I've googled, though it didn't help the situation any - I assume either because I set up the route wrong, or because it's not a feasible solution for this problem.

I want to preserve the 192.168.1 subnet precisely the way it functions today, while also being able to talk to the 10.0.0 device. If static route does not work here, what is your most clever solution to a situation of this sort?

Toplogy edit:

```
External Gateway --> 
    10.0.0.1 (bridge device) --> 
        192.168.1.1 (router) --> 
        192.168.1.5 (switch) --> 
        192.168.1.10 (terminal)
```

Routing table

```
Destination     Gateway    Flags    Use     Mtu     Netif
default         80.213.4.1  UGS    30655    1500    re0 
8.8.8.8         80.213.4.1  UGHS   2        1500    re0 
10.0.0.0/24     80.213.4.1  UGS    6183     1500    re0 ' <--?
80.213.4.0/22   link#1      U      12785    1500    re0 
80.213.4.124    link#1      UHS    0        16384   lo0 
127.0.0.1       link#7      UH     59       16384   lo0 
130.67.15.198   80.213.4.1  UGHS   0        1500    re0 
192.168.1.0/24  link#3      U      212101   1500    re2 
192.168.1.1     link#3      UHS    0        16384   lo0 
192.168.2.0/24  192.168.2.2 UGS    0        1500    ovpns1  
192.168.2.1     link#8      UHS    0        16384   lo0 
192.168.2.2     link#8      UH     0        1500    ovpns1
```

[image]

Nmap scans:

```
nmap -sP 10.0.0.0/24
nmap -sn 10.0.0.0/24
nmap -sL -n 10.0.0.0/24
```

All scans either return nothing or every IP in the subnet.

Latest edit:

I located the device, but have yet to establish a connection. On the router (192.168.1.1):

```
[admin@purgatory.vegardindustries.com]/root: ifconfig re0 add 10.0.0.2/24
[admin@purgatory.vegardindustries.com]/root: ifconfig -a
re0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=8209b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,WOL_MAGIC,LINKSTATE>
        ether 14:cc:20:06:5e:0e
        inet6 fe80::16cc:20ff:fe06:5e0e%re0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
        inet 80.213.4.124 netmask 0xfffffc00 broadcast 80.213.7.255
        inet 10.0.0.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.0.255
[admin@purgatory.vegardindustries.com]/root: arp -a
[...]
? (10.0.0.2) at 14:cc:20:06:5e:0e on re0 permanent [ethernet]
? (10.0.0.1) at cc:5d:4e:9c:ad:c0 on re0 expires in 328 seconds [ethernet]
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, or what you've tried.  If it's on the WAN side, then just surf to it....?  What's happening when you try?  Keep in mind: [10.x.x.x are considered private IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), so your router may not be willing to route to it....

Comment: The router and the device aren't on the same subnet, so I can't surf to it. I am asking how to communicate between the subnets, á la a the functionality I thought static route would give me. I have tried adding a static route, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Every computer you access on the Internet is in a different subnet, how do you think you're access those? The default routing in your router will most likely be something to the effect of "For every address not on this LAN try WAN".

Comment: Yes, that was my point - the router doesn't "know" how to route to it, and I am trying to rectify that situation. Adding a static route for 10.0.0.0/24 didn't solve anything, causing me to ask here.

Comment: "Adding a static route for 10.0.0.0/24 didn't solve anything, causing me to ask here" please edit your question and add this important info, along with anything else you've already tried, and what the results were of those trials.

Comment: And does the device on the 10.0.0.0/x subnet have a route back to your 192.168.1.0/24 subnet?  It would help if you updated your question with actual commands attempted, and more detail (ascii art?) of the topology.

Comment: Updated. I don't know precisely what you mean "route back"?

Comment: The routing table listed (not the screenshot) is from the 10.0.0.1 "bridge device" ?  For two IP nodes to communicate, there must be routes from A to B, and from B to A.  Your question is asking about getting from A to B, but even if A was able to send a request to B, you wouldn't see the response if B had no route(s) back to A.

Comment: No, the table originates on 192.168.1.1. I don't have any way of accessing (much less setting) the routing table for 10.0.0.1 since I can't reach it. I am beginning to assume that means I can't solve the situation with the current topology.

Answer (score 2):

Add a route, to your router for the gateway to access that device.

You'll likely find it in the static routing section of PFsense, but it's a long time since I've used it. Also, you'll need to make sure the filtering of 'private' addresses is turned off (I believe it's on by default in pfsense) as you wouldn't normally expect to see that IP range on the 'WAN' side of your router.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm not filtering private networks. I already tried adding a static route for 10.0.0.0/24, but that seemed to not work. I guess my real question is narrowing down to what I am doing wrong when creating the route.

Comment: By default I think the routes will be added on the lan side, you need to specify it exists on the wan side.

Comment: The route shows up with WAN as its interface.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the easiest way (that doesn't involve changing the IP of my terminal or my router) to access a subnet that neither of these devices are operating on?

In Linux, an interface can have 2 or more IP addresses.

> `ip addr add 192.168.99.1/24 dev eth0`

for example.  It won't disturb any existing IP address.  If you can get a shell to this device try it.

Remove it by replacing `add` above with `del`.

If your default route can't route to that subnet, which is likely - it's been a while since I did this but I think you get a "free" route to, for example, `192.168.99.0/24` just by virtue of the above (a "directly connected" route).

If you have issues clear your ARP table with an `arp -d` from a root shell.

Comment: I seem to be able to access 10.0.0.0/24 having used the BSD equivalent of your suggestion. I haven't found the device yet, but I have a few things to verify. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Turns out the device now shows up in the router's ARP table, but it isn't reachable by anything on 192.168.1.0. Is that normal? Another user mentioned a "route back" that, if lacking, might impede the connection.

Comment: Ok ... after thinking - normally you *want* disparate subnets to not talk to each other without a router in between.  Try adding a route to 10.0.0.0/24 through that interface to see if it works.  If not, you are looking at having to set up IP forwarding or use something like `rinetd` to "manually" forward if you can set that up on this device.

Comment: When you say "add a route to 10.0.0.0/24", do you mean something other than the route I've already added (table and screenshot in OP)?

Comment: Nope, that's what I was talking about.  I bet you need something in the middle to forward it.  Only other thing I can think of that could possibly be relevant is "policy routing" but that's only if you want 2 sets of IPs in the same subnets to be affected by 2 different routing tables.  Not sure if that will help.  Sorry.  :(

Comment: Don't be sorry, you've been tremendous help so far. Your original suggestion has given me further inspiration... :-)